# Does a .NET Framework installation interfere with existing VB6 runtime or COM installations?

Tags: .net, vb6

Consider this situation: There's a critical VB6 desktop application running on a production box. There is a possibility of installing a .NET application that queries the same DB that the VB6 application queries, which is an SQL Server 2000 DB. The VB6 application also depends on third-party ActiveX controls (registered .ocx files).

The concern is - will the .NET Framework installation replace any files or break the VB6 runtime in any way. In other words, can we safely assume that an installation of the .NET Framework is completely independent of any previous VB6 installations and will not interfere with the running application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is critical, clone the production system and install the .NET Framework on the clone first to test if there is any interference with your new application.

As Randolpho already said, the .NET Framework installation is independent from the VB6 runtime. But be aware that you must reboot your production server, and that you should also check whether your new .NET applications interferes with the legacy VB6 application.

In general, it is good practice for critical systems to have such a staging server for testing and Q&A that mirrors your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the .NET framework is completely independent of previous COM components and the VB6 runtime.

Comment: Thanks @Randolpho. Do you have any official Microsoft link that states this? This would help if I were to make a case for installing the Framework.

Comment: @faredoon: do you know... after searching, I can't find anything *now* that states that explicitly. I know back in 2001 there were plenty of articles that stated it. The closest I can find is the [.NET 1.1 Framework overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw4w595w%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), which states that it's stand-alone and different from unmanaged execution environments (such as vb6).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I tried searching too. If you come across anything more specific, do post it here. Appreciate it.